# ASP.NET Core Web API can't find file in MongoDB GridFS

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, gridfs

I'm working on some project of mine that will use MongoDB GridFS to store multimedia (video, audio) files.

The project uses ASP.NET Core Web API to serve the data to clients.
The problem is that I never get the reference to the file. The file cannot be found in the database, the sames goes when I try to find the file by id.

But when I used the NoSQLBooster for MongoDB and make query to mongodb using the same values I get the correct result with the file I'm looking for.

The code from the MongoDB GridFS documentation also does not work.
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/gridfs/findingfiles/

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("db_gridfs");

var movieName = "The Video.mp4";

IGridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(database);
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Filename, movieName);

using (var cursor = await bucket.FindAsync(filter))
{
    var fileInfo = (await cursor.ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Id)}: {fileInfo.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Filename)}: {fileInfo.Filename}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Length)}: {fileInfo.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.ChunkSizeBytes)}: {fileInfo.ChunkSizeBytes}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.UploadDateTime)}: {fileInfo.UploadDateTime}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>API_Test</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.13.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.GridFS" Version="2.13.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

MongoDB Shell

```
> show dbs
admin           0.000GB
config          0.000GB
db_gridfs       0.029GB
largFiles       0.022GB
local           0.000GB
myLocalMongoDB  0.000GB

> use db_gridfs
switched to db db_gridfs


> show collections
videos.chunks
videos.files


> db.videos.files.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61800905290dc9ea5307ff8d"), "length" : 23870090, "chunkSize" : 261120, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2021-11-01T15:34:29.262Z"), "filename" : "The Video.mp4", "contentType" : "video/mp4" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6183e337718935cd919bdc0e"), "length" : 8221882, "chunkSize" : 261120, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2021-11-04T13:42:15.929Z"), "filename" : "The Video 2.mp4", "contentType" : "video/mp4" }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that anything can be visible from the above question, but I vote that you use different connection strings or dbs in these cases. You can check whether the file you're looking for actually exists via this shell query:

```
    MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> use db_gridfs
    switched to db db_gridfs
    MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> show collections
    fs.chunks
    fs.files
    MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.fs.files.find({})
    { "_id" : ObjectId("618423b7bb151f094ea82aee"), "length" : NumberLong(3), "chunkSize" : 261120, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2021-11-04T18:17:30.905Z"), "md5" : "5289df737df57326fcdd22597afb1fac", "filename" : "test.txt" }
```

where the mentioned file is inserted via modified code that you provided:

```
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var database = client.GetDatabase("db_gridfs");

        var movieName = "test.txt";

        IGridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(database);
        var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Filename, movieName);
        // inserting
        bucket.UploadFromBytes(movieName, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });

        using (var cursor = bucket.Find(filter))
        {
            var fileInfo = (cursor.ToList()).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Id)}: {fileInfo.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Filename)}: {fileInfo.Filename}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.Length)}: {fileInfo.Length}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.ChunkSizeBytes)}: {fileInfo.ChunkSizeBytes}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(fileInfo.UploadDateTime)}: {fileInfo.UploadDateTime}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**:
looking at your code, you didn't specify a busket name which means that by default you will search files in `fs.files`, it should be:

```
 IGridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(database, new GridFSBucketOptions() { BucketName = "videos" });
```

Comment: I did used MongoDB shell, NoSQLBooster for MongoDB app  and as I mentioned earlier. The file exist in database but using FindAsync() function does not give me any results (no file/files found).

Comment: See code above where I insert file(UploadFromBytes) and then read(Find) it. If it doesn't work for you, then 99.9% that you use different connection strings or dbs

Comment: Try reproduce your behavior in a simple console application with the same connection string, I doubt you will have any issues

Comment: also see update

Comment: I just read your message, although I myself came to the conclusion recently that actually the problem was in not providing the new GridFSBucketOptions() object in Find()/FindAsync() method when searching a collection with not default name as you mentioned in the update.
Thanks for the reply dododo.